# Why is boost::dynamic_bitset a template?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-dynamic-bitset

I have used `boost::dynamic_bitset` before as `boost::dynamic_bitset<>`, without really thinking about why it is templated.

Though I can understand why `std::bitset` is templated (the template type is used to specify the size of the bitset), I have now encountered some code of the form `boost::dynamic_bitset<unsigned char>` and I can't figure out what's the point of the template type.

How is `boost::dynamic_bitset<unsigned char>` different from `boost::dynamic_bitset<>`? Should one be used over the other in any situation?

Comment: did you read [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html#template-parameters) ?

Comment: @tobi303 I have, but can't see what `Block` means in this context nor why would someone use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html#description):

```
template <typename Block, typename Allocator>
class dynamic_bitset { // ...
```

The most obvious advantage of `dynamic_bitset` being a template is that you can specify your own `Allocator` type. This can be useful for a plethora of reasons *(performance, memory contiguity, debugging)*. `dynamic_bitset` does allocate through `Allocator` if its internal storage needs to grow to accommodate more bits.

Additionally, it allows you to specify a `Block` type, which is the underlying primitive used to represent a bunch of bits. You might want to change the block type depending on the platform you're on or depending on how much memory you're willing to use *(e.g. a smaller `Block` type would result in less wasted memory if not all bits are significant)*.

Comment: So in this case, `unsigned char` means that it uses an array of `unsigned char`s internally to store the bits? But this shouldn't make any difference from the outside, apart from memory usage, right?

Comment: @user2891462: it's also useful for interoperability with existing buffers. See `boost::to_block_range` for an example.